# How do I handle WM_NCCALCSIZE and make chrome-like interface?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, user-interface, google-chrome

I'm currently using Google Chrome as my main browser. I wondered how the developers put the custom titlebar, because I wanted to incorporate into one of my own applications.

If you guys don't know what I'm talking about, here's a picture:

[image: Screenshot]

I found an article about the interface, which is here:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/33870516-9868-48d3-ab53-6269d9979598

However, I don't know how to do this. I'm currently using VC++ Express. Can anyone give me step by step instructions and how to get an interface like that? Except I don't want tabs on top.

I'm writing this in Win32.

Answer (score 3):

If memory serves, the *main* things you need to handle aren't WM_NCCALCSIZE, but WM_NCHITTEST and WM_NCPAINT.

WM_NCHITTEST is what tells the system when the cursor is over the title bar, so you need to take a cursor position and decide whether it's over the area you consider "title bar". In particular, if the user clicks and drags with the cursor in this area, the whole window gets dragged.

WM_NCPAINT is just like WM_PAINT except for the non-client area -- i.e., this is when you need to actually draw whatever you're going to for the title bar (and window borders, if memory serves).

I should add that I haven't played with this in quite a while. There's almost certainly more I'm not remembering right now.

Comment: What would I have to do exactly? (I'm a newb) Please help, my email is shadowhunter9636@gmail.com

Comment: This answer is wrong. If you want to create your customized border you will have to modify at least WM_NCCALCSIZE and WM_NCPAINT while WM_NCHITTEST is only relevant for clicks on the buttons in the titelbar.

Comment: I've found that Windows 7 behaves differently from Windows 10 here. I was able to disable the nonclient area by returning 0 on WM_NCCALCSIZE, but in Windows 10 specifically, it would draw title bar buttons anyway unless I also handled WM_NCHITTEST myself. I wish I knew a more standardized way of customizing ithe title bar without having to handle the details of Windows messages and version-specific quirks.

Answer (score 3):

OK, the answer is simple:

Chomre simply does not use the Windows built in functionality for drawing a frame border, titlebar, titlebar buttons, etc..

When you call GetWindowRect(hChromeWindow) and GetClientRect(hChromeWindow) you will notice that the rectangles are identical. This means that Chrome turns off all Windows functionality for drawing a border (simply return 0 in WM_NCCALSIZE without doing anything else) and then they draw EVERYTHING into the client area.

So in WM_PAINT they draw the titlebar and the upper part of the window (URL bar, tabs, etc..) together. In WM_NCPAINT they do nothing.

This is not the common way to do it, but the easiest, and it is bullet-proof.

By the way: Java applications do the same.